# load data local infile user provided VALUES

Tags: php, mysql, load-data-infile

My project requires external CSV files to be uploaded to a database every week and required outputs are extracted whenever required. Currently am using the below to browse through a HTML form and upload to the table. It works fine!

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

$handle = fopen($file,"r");
while(($fileop = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",")) !==false)
{
  $placement_name = $fileop[2];
  $statistics_date = $fileop[0];
  $impressions = $fileop[5];
  $clicks = $fileop[6];


 $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'table'(source,advertiser,campaign,placement_name,statistics_date,impressions,clicks) VALUES ('xxx','yyy','zzz','$placement_name','$statistics_date','$impressions',' $clicks')");}
```

But now, we might need to do this on a daily basis and automated (which we hope to do with scheduled cron jobs), so decision was to use LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE. As you could see the values inserted for `source`, `advertiser` and `campaign` are custom ones. How could we use the `LOAD DATA...` instead of the browse function?